# pattern searching in R using loop

Tags: r, pattern-matching

I am doing pattern searching:

```
  library(stringr)
  str_count(data,"\\<1\\>")
```

and that is searching "1" in data.I need to do

```
  str_count(data,"\\<i \\>")
```

where i={1,2,...20}

How could this be done.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can just do something like this:

```
vec <- 1:20 
sapply(vec, function(x) str_count(data, sprintf("\\%s\\>", x)))
```

That is, use `sprintf` to construct your pattern.

Comment: How is `\\1\\>` even working? I get an error for an invalid regular expression.

Comment: @thelatemail, I didn't test for validity. I'm just being their monkey at the keyboard trying to get what they claim to want :-) (The answer should be easy enough to interpret to be able to construct a valid pattern that they might be interested in though.)

Comment: Infinite monkeys at infinite typewriters and potentially the code might eventually work.

Comment: @AnandaMahto: Thanks a lot, just wanted to make a change in the solution you sent     sapply(vec, function(x) str_count(data, sprintf("\\<%s\\>", x))) , i.e. < before %s

Comment: How about removing the loop and collapsing vec with '|'? Wouldn't that work? (Not tested..)

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `paste`

```
library(stringr)
sapply(paste0("\\<",1:20, "\\>"), function(x) str_count(data, x))
```

Or perhaps

```
table(1:20,factor(str_extract(data, '\\d+'), levels=1:20))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
data <- paste0("\\<", sample(1:20,20,replace=TRUE),  "\\>")
```